# Generate PDF from a big image using Apache FOP

Tags: java, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I would like to generate a PDF from an image, using Apache FOP and XSLT. However, if image s bigger, then PDF document page, then it only gets as much space as it is available on the page (including right and bottom margin). So, part of the image is out of page bounds.

Is this possible to setup fop so that if image can't be fitted into the page it is automatically splitted into the multiple pages?

Here is my xslt template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java"
    xmlns:dp="http://www.dpawson.co.uk"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:f="Functions"
    xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-datatypes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="java">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="image-print-path" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4"
                    page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="2cm"
                    margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="20pt" margin-bottom="35pt" />
                    <fo:region-before extent=".5in"/>
                    <fo:region-after extent=".5in"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
                <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before" text-align="left">
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt">
                        Print
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:static-content>

                <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt" text-align="left">
                        something else
                    </fo:block>
                <!--    TODO: add current date, page number -->
                </fo:static-content>

                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt" page-break-after="always">
                        <fo:external-graphic src="{$image-print-path}"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like there's anything in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_external-graphic) that can format in the way you need. This leaves you with a few options:

1. check the graphic before you inject it into your XSL workflow and cut it up into a number of images to use across multiple pages
2. inspect the graphic to determine it's dimensions and create a page size big enough to contain it, and leave the slicing to printers
3. set `content-width` to `scale-down-to-fit` to show the entire graphic on a single page

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. In the end my solution was splitting image into the pieces to be able fit on the page.